# Python. Detect changes in vector direction

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `y` that either increments or decrements by 1. What I want is to create a another vector `y2` that shows when `y1` changed direction.

I can't figure out how to do this in `numpy`.

**EDIT updated plot, due to missing comma in y**

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

**EDIT: Fixed missing comma in y**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,1])

x = np.arange(len(y))

y2 = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0])

plt.plot(x, y, label='y - Actual')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='y2 - Desired')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Now also handles out of spec inputs (increments outside -1, 0, 1).

Here's a slightly faster (for the time being) way (pp is me, D is @Divakar):

```
# n = 10
# pp                    0.02363790 ms
# D                     0.03705720 ms
# n = 1000
# pp                    0.03609150 ms
# D                     0.05877410 ms
# n = 1000000
# pp                   22.63471480 ms
# D                    36.92147740 ms
```

Code including benchmarking:

```
import numpy as np

import types
from timeit import timeit

def setup_data(n, allow_out_of_spec=True):
    if allow_out_of_spec:
        data = {'y': np.cumsum(np.random.randint(0, 10, (n,))
                               * np.random.randint(-1, 2, (n,)))}
    else:
        data = {'y': np.cumsum(np.random.randint(-1, 2, (n,)))}
    return data

# mine
def f_pp(y, allow_out_of_spec=True):
    if allow_out_of_spec:
        d = np.sign(np.diff(y))
    else:
        d = np.diff(y)
    ud = np.flatnonzero(d)
    uds = d[ud]
    chng = ud[np.r_[True, uds[1:] != uds[:-1]]]

    out = np.zeros(len(y), dtype=int)
    out[1:][chng] = d[chng]
    return out

# @Divakar's
def f_D(y):
    s0 = np.flatnonzero(y[1:] > y[:-1])+1
    s1 = np.flatnonzero(y[1:] < y[:-1])+1

    idx0 = np.searchsorted(s1,s0,'right')
    s0c = s0[np.r_[True,idx0[1:] > idx0[:-1]]]

    idx1 = np.searchsorted(s0c,s1,'right')
    s1c = s1[np.r_[True,idx1[1:] > idx1[:-1]]]

    out = np.zeros(len(y),dtype=int)
    out[s0c] = 1
    out[s1c] = -1
    return out

for n in (10, 1000, 1000000):
    data = setup_data(n)
    ref = np.array(f_pp(**data))
    print(f'n = {n}')
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        try:
            assert np.allclose(ref, func(**data))
            print("{:16s}{:16.8f} ms".format(name[2:], timeit(
                'f(**data)', globals={'f':func, 'data':data}, number=10)*100))
        except:
            print("{:16s} apparently failed".format(name[2:]))
```

Comment: I was struggling with this for a long time, before I asked the question. Wish I had done so earlier! Very smart mate!

Comment: It provides an output similar to Divakar's, but not quite: `all(detect_ups_downs(y) ==y2)
True
all(f_pp(y) ==y2)
False`

Comment: @JamesSchinner That's because there is a comma missing in `y`, there are two `-1`s directly next to each other which are summed to yield `-2`. So `y` does not actually conform with your spec _increments or decrements by 1_.

Comment: Seems to be getting different results for a bit more generic case - e.g. : `y = np.array([0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,-1-1,0,0,1,0,8,8,9,-4,-6,4,-2,2])`.

Comment: @Divakar your example is out of spec, too. And if you really want the same behavior you can change my first line to `d = np.sign(np.diff(y))`.

Comment: This is my mistake for, leaving out that comma. @PaulPanzer you have answered the question more closely, I will leave your answer as accepted for this reason (for my purposes I will be using your solution). Divakar's
solution will probably be more useful to the boarder public.

Comment: Looks really good, Tried few others, but nothings seems to beat this.

Comment: @Divakar High praise, indeed. Wish I could frame this and put on my mantel piece ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way -

```
def detect_ups_downs(y):
    s0 = np.flatnonzero(y[1:] > y[:-1])+1
    s1 = np.flatnonzero(y[1:] < y[:-1])+1

    idx0 = np.searchsorted(s1,s0,'right')
    s0c = s0[np.r_[True,idx0[1:] > idx0[:-1]]]

    idx1 = np.searchsorted(s0c,s1,'right')
    s1c = s1[np.r_[True,idx1[1:] > idx1[:-1]]]

    out = np.zeros(len(y),dtype=int)
    out[s0c] = 1
    out[s1c] = -1
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [92]: y = np.array([0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,-1-1,0,0,1,0,8,8,9,-4,-6,4,-2,2])

In [93]: np.c_[y, detect_ups_downs(y)]
Out[93]: 
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  0],
       [ 3,  0],
       [ 4,  0],
       [ 1, -1],
       [ 0,  0],
       [-2,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 0, -1],
       [ 8,  1],
       [ 8,  0],
       [ 9,  0],
       [-4, -1],
       [-6,  0],
       [ 4,  1],
       [-2, -1],
       [ 2,  1]])
```

Comment: Great work! There are a few `numpy` functions in in your answer I need to go read about!

Answer (score -1):

Try taking a derivative:

```
dy = y[1:] - y[:-1]
```

Then check if adjacent points have switched derivative signs:

```
increasing = dy > 0
decreasing = dy < 0
saddle = dy == 0

change_increasing = increasing[1:] and decreasing[:-1]
change_decreasing = decreasing[1:] and increasing[:-1]
```

Bring all that information together:

```
changes = np.zeros_like(dy)

changes[0] = (1 * increasing[0]) + (-1 * decreasing[0])
changes[1:][change_increasing] = 1
changes[1:][change_decreasing] = -1
changes[saddle] = 0

print(changes)
```

Comment: `change_increasing` would have one lesser element. So, how is `changes[change_increasing]` possible?

Comment: @Divakar Good point. This is looking much grosser than I had initially hoped.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work yet (not giving the expected output on given sample).

Comment: @Divakar Huh, I guess the particular output expected by OP requires tracking of state. My example only works based on local information.